# Custom select with border radius around all elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a custom select item with a border radius. As you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/cb9t8ny5/, the border radius works well when the item is not expanded. However, when you expand it, the border radius is then separately applied to the currently selected item and the rest of the list. I would like it to apply to all of them as a whole like this diagram:

[image: diagram]

The current border radius was achieved with

```
.select-selected {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.select-items {
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

however I cannot workout how to do it as described.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question itself.

Comment: @justDan please note that it is a license violation to copy substantive code from another site with an unknown/unstated license over to Stack Overflow, where code is licensed under CC by-SA 4.0 (or 3.0 prior to an earlier date).

Comment: @TylerH Sorry about that and thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @justDan No worries. For small stuff or boilerplate code, it's no issue, but the jsfiddle contains a *lot* of customization/additional stuff in this case

Comment: @TylerH I'm confused?

Comment: @MazPaok About what?

Comment: @TylerH Why are you talking to this guy?

Comment: @MazPaok He suggested an edit to your question that I rejected and I wanted to make sure he knew why.